# Ways to define y in terms of a variable and a single constant.

Tags: geometry

I’m trying to teach myself mathematics from a book and I don’t have access to a teacher.  I’ve been able to work independently so far, but with one challenge question I’m hitting a wall.

The challenge is to define y in terms of r for a shape with a fixed perimeter and then to find the area of a composite shape using that definition.

Where y is the side of a rectangle with perimeter fixed at 6 and has a semicircle on top with the radius r (see diagram).

When I try to formulate this myself I come to: (6-2r-πr)/2 or: (6-r(2π))/2.  This appears incompatible with the next step however which is to find the area of the shape with the form A = ar^2 + br where a and b are constants.

The way I read that last part is that I ought to have derived a formulation for the side (y) that is a constant.  I’ve looked and this and looked at this and looked at this again, but I can’t see another way to define y.

Could anyone be so kind as to offer me even a hint?

[image: composite shape]

Comment: Is the perimeter of the rectangle fixed at $6$, or the whole shape? If its just the rectangle, then you know $2y+2s = 6$ where $s$ is the short side on the bottom's length. Can you write $s$ in terms of $r$?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Perimeter of the whole shape is 6.

Comment: Then you have $2y + s + \pi r = 6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the perimeter of the rectangle with one side $ y $ is 6, then, since its other side is equal to $ 2 r $, you have $ 2 y + 2(2 r) = 6 \implies y = 3 - 2 r $.

On the other hand, if the perimeter of the shape in your picture is 6, then you have $ 2 y + \frac{2 \pi r}{2} = 6 \implies y = 3 - \frac{\pi}{2} r $.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I agree with the formulation of the side when P = 6.  Perhaps my struggle really with area formulation given this.

Comment: Using the further reduced 3 - (pi/2)r formulation I was able to arrive at an area definition that conformed to the format stated in the challenge.

Comment: You are welcome!